# Is linking with libraries the same as linking to a library linking with libraries

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, shared-libraries

I have a project `foo`, which is linked to `libA`, `libB`, and `libC`.

Now is that the same as having project `foo`, which is linked to `libZ`, which is linked to `libA`, `libB`, and `libC`.

I ask because I write a wrapper library for SDL2, which is linked to `lSDL2_image`.
However when I compile a project using my wrapper library it complains about undefined symbols, and as soon as I link my project against `libSDL2_image` as well, it works.

Comment: No, you can't link one library to another.   Which is why you get the linker error of course.  You can at best use a library management tool to merge them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any code calls functions from `libA`, `libB` and `libC`, the linker must be aware of them for finding the called symbols during linking stage. No matter if the caller is your main application or other library that makes part of your project.